# Pulling Drive activity report through GCP, is there a way to see folder path?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I am supposed to generate drive activity report so we can track what type of file users are using and where is the file being created (My Drive/shared drive).

I used the GAM command to pull drive activity report which has various fields except for the root path.

Does anyone know a way i can manipulate that so i can get a field that shows folder path as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom menu that iterates through a table of data, the data must have a column with the file IDs of interest and 2 additional columns for owner and path, since the file can be owned by either a user or a shared drive. The user running the function must have Super Admin rights to access files owned by other users and the user in question must be a member of a shared drive for the file to be located. My previous implementation as a custom function failed to address a limitation of this feature where advanced services are inaccessible.

[image: Sample table with the required columns]

The custom menu is created as explained in this documentation article https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus. There must be a trigger that executes when the sheet opens the menu is created.

In addition to that the code requires the use of Advanced Services, Google Drive must be added following the steps of this other article https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services. The advanced service will ask for authorization but the first time the code is executed. You may expedite the process by creating an empty function and running it.

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  ui.createMenu('File ownership').addItem('Read data', 'readData').addToUi();
}

function readData() {
  var sheetData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

  var i = 0;

  for (; i < sheetData.length; i++){
    if (sheetData[0][i] == '')
      break;
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('There are ' + i + ' cells with data.');

  for (i = 1; i < sheetData.length; i++){
    var fileID = sheetData[i][0];

    var owner = getFileOwner(fileID);
    var path = getFilePath(fileID);

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i + 1,2).setValue(owner);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i + 1,3).setValue(path );
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('The owner and file path have been populated');  
}

function getFilePath(fileID, filePath = ""){
  try {
    var file = Drive.Files.get(fileID,{
      supportsAllDrives: true
    });

    if (!file.parents[0])
      return "/" + filePath;

    var parent = file.parents[0];
    var parentFile = Drive.Files.get(parent.id,{ supportsAllDrives: true });
    var parentPath = parentFile.title;

    if (parent.isRoot || parentFile.parents.length == 0)
      return "/" + filePath;
    else {
      return getFilePath(
        parentFile.id,
        parentPath + "/" + filePath);
    }
  }
  catch (GoogleJsonResponseException){
    return "File inaccesible"
  }
  
}

function getFileOwner(fileID){
  try {
    var file = Drive.Files.get(
      fileID,
      {
        supportsAllDrives: true
      });

    var driveId = file.driveId;

    if (driveId){
      var driveName = Drive.Drives.get(driveId).name;

      return  driveName + "(" + driveId + ")";
    }

    var ownerEmailAddress = file.owners[0].emailAddress;
    return ownerEmailAddress;
  }
  catch (GoogleJsonResponseException){
    return "File inaccesible"
  }
}
```

After executing the function, it will take significantly longer the more files IDs it has, the cells will be updated with their respective owner and path.

[image: Results after executing the function]

**Note:** with a Super Admin account you can programmatically create a view permission for shared drives you don't have access to using APIs or Apps Script, you may submit a separate question for more details or read the documentation in the developer page at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions.

Comment: I tried this out and get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" on line 2.

Comment: Currently reviewing.

Comment: any updates about this?

Comment: Sorry for the late update, I tried different methods to obtain the path of a file and this appears to be the simplest one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these particular GAM commands so you can edit them later to gather information of the folders and root folders:

```
gam user <User Email Address> print filetree depth 0 showmimetype gfolder excludetrashed todrive
```

You can edit the depth, for example orphaned folders when using -1. I am not familiar with which command you use, but you might need to mix or add some fields so it shows the root folder or path.

```
gam user <User Email Address> print filelist todrive select 1Yvxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxjif9 showmimetype gfolder fields id
```

You might need to add over your command something like "print filetree" or "show filepath"

****Reference**:**

- https://github.com/taers232c/GAMADV-XTD3/wiki/Users-Drive-Files-Display

Comment: Thanks for the answer, while this may work, it is user and file specific. I have to generate reports for multiple users at a time and of all the files they have created.

Comment: What is the GAM command you have?  Based on the documentation it might be a good idea as I suggest what to add in order to pull what you need. If not, it might be a limitation itself on GAM or the Drive API when pulling reports not showing the path itself and might need a manual option using a similar script like the one above.

Comment: This is the command I am using;
"gam redirect csv - todrive report drive user ***.*** previousmonths 1 event create"
Which creates a google sheet document with various fields. And yes you are right I had cross checked, it does take information from Drive API so I don't think I can add fields as I like. Will look into manually adding the folder path using file ID.